# How can I modify a kernel size image data as an input for CNN in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, input, deep-learning, kernel, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to create a 1x1x198 input for my CNN from a 100x100x198 data(image).

I'm using Hyperspectral Imaging data (jasper), however, if I want to process and plot their endmembers through a Convolution Neural Network I have to modify the data in 1x1x198 kernel sizes.

I am trying to write the Matlab code for the following paper. I will appreciate any help regarding the paper's Matlab code. IEEE paper: [Hyperspectral unmixing via deep convolutional neural networks](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8432512/)

 Thank you
[image]
[image]

Comment: The data are 100x100 images that were taken in 198 different bands. As demonstrated in the figures the input to the CNN is 1x1x198 (or 3x3x198). Hope this clarifies a few things.

Comment: Hope I understood your question correctly. In order to extract a 1x1x198 slice from your 100x100x198 data, you only need to do `x(10,10,:)` which means the tenth row and tenth columns of all 198 channels. It returns a 1x1x198 matrix (i.e., vector). Then you can feed this matrix to your CNN. You probably need to reshape 1x1x198 to a vector of 1x198 (or 198x1) and stack multiple of them to create your batch. Look at the CNN input layer and figure out what should be the shape of the input.

Comment: Was my comment helpful? If so, let me know that I answer your question. Thanks